# How can I prevent PPT from increasing the number of colors in a slide it exports?

Tags: images, microsoft-powerpoint

I've created a PPT 365 test file with one slide, which contains a single imported image in one color (red). The slide thus uses exactly two colors: white (the slide background) and red (the image). However, when I save the slide as PNG, the resulting image has 16 colors. If I save it as TIF or BMP, there are 256 colors. If I save it as JPG, there are 49306. I want to have PPT generate a slide image with precisely two colors: white and red.

In PPT 365's Options, I've checked *Do not compress images in file*, and when using *Save As* for any of the above formats, I've confirmed that *More Options...>Tools>Compress Pictures* has *High fidelity* checked.

I'm using Windows 10. To count the number of colors in an image, I'm using XnView MP.

Comment: You've posted the same question in Answers.Microsoft.com, which is fine. There are already several answers there, so please have a look.  You can pretty much ignore the "answers" from the people listed as Independent Advisers. Total waste of pixels. If only they'd learn to read the question before answering it, y'know?

Comment: I typically post here first, falling back on the Microsoft forums only if SuperUser fails to yield useful information. My experience with the Microsoft forums has been disappointing, though sometimes useful information eventually emerges.

Comment: You probably have more colours because of anti-aliasing (and the lossy quality of JPEGs for that particular format).

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe As I mentioned, posting in both places is fine. Your particular question seems to have elicited more than its fair share of irrelevant/idiotic responses from the usual sources of such things. Generally, you can trust responses from people flagged as MVPs (who'll generally correct one another's errors). The people with MSFT badges are a mixed lot; some on the PPT section are decent, some provide little more than scripted suggestions. The people badged as Independent Advisors are mostly useless.  I think if you look back over the thread there, you'll see what I mean.